# What is UPCRTD attribute in IBMi AS400?

Tags: jt400, websphere

Could anyone tell me what is does UPCRTD attribute mean in IBMi AS400 system?
I guess this is a user profile creation date-time, but I didn't find any official documentation which simply says, that UPCRTD means user profile creation date time.
Can anyone please refer any document I can find useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find this detailed information in a document. UPCRTD is one of the column of the result table of the command DSPUSRPRF TYPE(*BASIC) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)

You can see [there](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/dspusrprf.htm) that this table has the same structure as QADSPUPB when TYPE(*BASIC)

The by SQL wou can find information about the column or your machine

```
select
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TEXT
from
    QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
where
    (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) = ('QSYS', 'QADSPUPB', 'UPCRTD');
```

gives

```
|TABLE_SCHEMA|TABLE_NAME|COLUMN_NAME|COLUMN_TEXT                                       |
|------------|----------|-----------|--------------------------------------------------|
|QSYS        |QADSPUPB  |UPCRTD     |Creation date: YYMMDD                             |
```

Answer (score 0):

UPRCRTD field is User Profile CReaTe Date

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP asked, exactly. ("Can anyone please refer any document I can find useful?")